# Connect to Wifi for 10 minutes then disconnect

Tags: raspbian, wifi, headless, systemd-startup

I use one of my Raspberry Pi as a headless desk clock and, apart from a reboot once a day which forces the OS to synchronise time to an NTP server, I would like to turn the WiFi off after that stage has completed, perhaps with a 10 minutes grace period in case I need to SSH in to perform maintenance.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: A possibilty is to use [timeout tool](https://linux.die.net/man/1/timeout) and down the interface in the programm arguments (but writing a proper script maybe is more usefull for cleaning ip addr on interface and other...) ex : `timeout 10m ifconfig wlan0 down`

Comment: If your network and NTP is done at raspberry start-up, just write a system unit file and put the timeout command ex: "`ExecStart=timeout 10m ifconfig wlan0 down`" that mean when the RPi start , the Rpi start your service and others services (ex:networking,you have internet)  and then execute the ifconfig command after 10m (timeout). When the interface is put in down the connectivity is stopped (you have not internet).

Comment: Many thanks. I appreciate there are many ways to achieve the same result with Linux, such a powerful OS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We do not know anything about your setup. The simplest way is to start a service on boot up that just delays 10 minutes (e.g. `sleep 600`) and then disables wifi. Here an idea for a generic systemd Unit file but not tested:

```
[Unit]
Description=Delay terminate wifi
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/sleep 600
ExecStop=/sbin/wpa_cli -iwlan0 terminate

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: Fantastic! I'll give it a go. Many thanks. It'll get me using systemd finally, also.